# PHP - How do I edit the contents of a PHP table that has been shown in a HTML table?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm doing a computing project for school coursework. It involves PHP, MySQL, and HTML - essentially building a web based app.

I have a PHP table called "users" in a database called "cp11641_users"
The content of this table has been echoed into a html table using mysql_query of the following:

```
<div id='accordion'>   <ul>
            <li>
              <a href='#one'><h4>Edit User Table</h4></a>
              <div id='one' class='accordion'>";
                $query = "SELECT * FROM users"; //You don't need a ; like you do in SQL 
                $result = mysql_query($query);

        echo "<table class='container'>"; // start a table tag in the HTML 
        echo " <thead>      <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>       
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Edit</th>   </tr> </thead>  "; 
    echo "<tbody>"; 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results 
echo "<tr><td>" . $row['first'] . "</td><td>" . $row['last'] . "</td><td>" . $row['username'] . "</td><td>" . "edit" . "</td></tr>";  } 
echo "</tbody> </table>"; //Close the table in HTML
              echo "</div>
            </li>";
```

This obviously puts the contents of the PHP table into a HTML table to view. But I want to be able to click the "edit" tab next to each row in the html table, and be able to take the data in that row to be changed/modified/deleted.

This is for the administrator page which should be able to change specific details for each user, that is essentially what I want to do.

I'm thinking that I would need to use the fact that the while loop uses an array from which I can pull specific rows of data (i.e. $Row[1]) and then put that in a $_POST[]? I'm not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MySQL should contain a unique id. Let's call that column id for now.

Then do something like

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results 
echo "<tr>
    <td>" . $row['first'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['last'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $row['username'] . " </td>
    <td><a href='editUser.php?id='".$row['id']."'> . "edit" . "</a></td>
</tr>";  }
```

Then in your editUser.php, add

```
$userid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ".$userid;
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Do you edits.

Comment: Hi, I was expecting this to work, however when I hover over the link generated, it only shows "http://cp11641.khsict.com/user_edit.php?id=", nothing proceeds the final part of the link, the id number doesn't proceed it, nothing?

Comment: Do not worry, I got it working! Great work man, it was a few misplaced "'" in the 2nd last line of code of yours in the while loop. But I've got it working now! Thanks a lot:)!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to put the edit functionality into a separate page. Essentially you have a link next to each item which sends to a separate page with a form that will then send the new information to update the item.

You're correct about putting that into a $_POST (it's actually more common to use $_GET for this though). You'll be sending the id through the 'edit' link so that your form knows what to edit. Then it will do a UPDATE in MySQL to that item when you submit.

Comment: I was thinking this too, it would make sense. It's just a matter of pulling the specific row from the array and putting it to use in the separate page. I'm going to experiment with $_POST['$Row[x]'];

Comment: If you're only going to edit one at a time, using ajax would be a valid method as well.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to use $_POST once you are not sending noting to server. Instead, you are requesting from server. So what you need is echo. Only.

Well first of all. I think you are doing that, but you need to have your page .php. Otherwise it will not work (without changes on htaccess).

It seems that your code is good, but you need the `<php? ?>` tags. Where are they?

```
    <div id='accordion'>   
            <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href='#one'><h4>Edit User Table</h4></a>
                  <div id='one' class='accordion'>
                    <php?
                    //Connect to your database ....
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM users";  
                    $result = mysql_query($query);

                    echo "<table class='container'>";
                    echo " <thead><tr><th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th><th>Username</th>         <th>Edit</th></tr></thead>  "; 
                    echo "<tbody>"; 
                      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   
                               echo "<tr><td>" . $row['first'] . "</td><td>" .                   $row['last'] . "</td><td>" . $row['username'] . "</td><td>" . "edit" . "</td></tr>";  } 

                    echo "</tbody> </table>"; 
                  ?>
       </div>
            </ul>
                </li>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hi this is only a chunk of the code, the <?php ?> tags are at the beginning (just before an if statement, to check if $_SESSION[] is an admin session and not standard)